# AngularJS custom directive using event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to create a custom directive that contains a text box that is shown, expanded and focused when a user clicks a button. And when the user clicks away from the expanded text box it should minimize, disappear and then show the original button. 
Here's what I have so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/Z6RzD/152/

Here is the section that I am having problems with:

```
  if (htmlTxtBox.addEventListener !== undefined) { 
  console.log("first");

  htmlTxtBox.addEventListener('focus', setFocus(), false);
  //this function is automatically called even when textBox is in focus              
  //htmlTxtBox.addEventListener('blur', setNoFocus(), false);
  console.log("ifHasFocus: " + scope.showInput);
} else if (htmlTxtBox.attachEvent != undefined) {
  console.log("second");
  htmlTxtBox.attachEvent('onfocus', setFocus());
  htmlTxtBox.attachEvent('onblur', setNoFocus());
} else {
  console.log("third");
  htmlTxtBox.onmouseover = setFocus();
  htmlTxtBox.onmouseout = setNoFocus();
}
```

And the corresponding functions that run with the event listener:

```
function setFocus()  {
        scope.$apply('showInput = true');
        console.log("setFocus: " + scope.showInput);    
    }
function setNoFocus(){
  scope.$apply('showInput = false');
  console.log("setNoFocus: " + scope.showInput);
}
```

My problem is that the setFocus and setNoFocus functions run no matter what. How can I structure these functions to where they run only when the textbox is focused or blurred?
I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
myApp.directive('replybox', function($timeout) {
    var linkFn = function(scope, element, attrs) {       
        scope.showInput = false;

        var button = element.find('button');        
        var input = element.find('input');

        button.bind("click", function() {
            scope.showInput = true;
            scope.$apply();

            input[0].focus();
            input.css({"width":"300px","transition":"1s"});            
        });

        input.bind('blur', function() {
            scope.showInput = false;            
            $timeout(function() { scope.$apply(); }, 1000);

            input.css({'width':'0px', 'transition':'1s'});
        });
    };    
...
```

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6RzD/156/).

Comment: That's the ticket! Now I'm trying to add a clear text icon...I tried the following but to no avail: http://jsfiddle.net/Z6RzD/158/  @Michael

Comment: Any specific reason for using `$.bind` and not `$.on`?

Comment: @pilau Angular's jqLite used to have only `bind` in earlier versions. That's changed in version 1.2RCx as they've replaced `bind` with `on`.

Comment: That's interesting, because in jQuery, `$.bind` allows listening to custom (non-DOM) events triggered with `$.event.trigger()` while `$.on` does not. But that shouldn't matter at all if you have your Angular architecture right.

Comment: why is scope.$apply() used in the event handler function?

Comment: scope.$apply() - A method you call to get your bindings to update. Ideally when $timeout or $ http is used there is no need to use $apply.(they do it for you)
When is it useful ? a broadcast method is triggered and listener is registered for it and needs UI updates, then $apply method can be used which in turn calls $digest!

Comment: Events bound this way will run repeatedly, forever, without provocation.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but to address the actual issue:

I believe `htmlTxtBox.addEventListener('focus', setFocus(), false);` should have just `setFocus` instead to pass the reference to the function rather than call it within the addEventListener call.